# Python lambda functions in Dataframe query

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a DataFrame with the following format (not the full size):

```
    +------------+------+-------+-------+-------+-----+
    |    Date    | Type |  T0   |  T1   |  T2   | ... |
    +------------+------+-------+-------+-------+-----+
    | 2017-01-05 | GBP  | 0.001 | 0.005 | 0.006 |     |
    | 2017-01-05 | USD  | 0.001 | 0.005 | 0.006 |     |
    | 2017-01-05 | EUR  | 0.001 | 0.005 | 0.006 |     |
    | 2017-01-05 | YAN  | 0.001 | 0.005 | 0.006 |     |
    | 2017-01-05 | ZBR  | 0.001 | 0.005 | 0.006 |     |
    | 2017-01-06 | GBP  | 0.001 | 0.005 | 0.006 |     |
    | 2017-01-06 | USD  | 0.001 | 0.005 | 0.006 |     |
    | .......... | ...  |...... |       |       |     |
    +------------+------+-------+-------+-------+-----+
```

Essentially I'm trying to filter this for the dates that are inbetween two specified and the Type equal to USD and GBP. I can currently do this for the date filter but not the Type filter:

```
df = df[(df.Date <= EndDate) & (df.Date >= StartDate)]
```

I can't seem to figure out how to filter for the Types I need (because it requires an "or" and not "&").

Furthermore I'd like to know how to do all this in one line. I have seen others do something similar using lambda but can't quite understand how all that works.

Can anyone help with the query and explain how I can achieve the same with a Lambda example?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need add condition with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df1 = df[(df.Date <= EndDate) & (df.Date >= StartDate) & (df.Type.isin(['USD','GBP']))]
```

Another solution with [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df2 = df.query('@EndDate >= Date >= @StartDate and Type in ["USD", "GBP"]')
```

Sample:

```
StartDate = '2017-01-04'
EndDate = '2017-01-05'
df1 = df[(df.Date <= EndDate) & (df.Date >= StartDate) & (df.Type.isin(['USD','GBP']))]
print (df1)
         Date Type     T0     T1     T2
0  2017-01-05  GBP  0.001  0.005  0.006
1  2017-01-05  USD  0.001  0.005  0.006

df2 = df.query('@EndDate >= Date >= @StartDate and Type in ["USD", "GBP"]')
print (df2)
         Date Type     T0     T1     T2
0  2017-01-05  GBP  0.001  0.005  0.006
1  2017-01-05  USD  0.001  0.005  0.006
```

Comment: Nice `query` solution :)

Comment: Great answer. To earn extra points, could you give an example of how this could be done with a lambda function please? :)

Comment: Do you think selection by callable? [Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-callable)